# Git keeps asking for ssh passphrase when SSH is already defined in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, git, ssh

I'm playing around with a personal GitLab account to get familiar with its' ins and outs. First, I followed [this primer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) on setting ssh keys and added public and private ED25519 keys to `~\.ssh`. I added the public key to my GitLab account. Then, using the `glab` CLI I was able to set up a repository which I could push to and pull from using `git`.

Unfortunately, `git` still prompts me for my SSH passphrase every time I try to push to the repo. I tried the following:

- Adding [known hosts entries](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-known_hosts-entries)
- [Verifying that I could connect](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#verify-that-you-can-connect) using `ssh -T https://gitlab.com/my_username`

The known host entries didn't have any noticeable effect on this behavior. Verifying I could connect threw the following error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname https://gitlab.com/my_username

Why is `git` asking me to provide my passphrase every time I push and how can I fix this once and for all?

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding your passphrase to the keychain using `ssh-add -K`, this will ask you the passphrase for the first time and later on it won't ask.

Answer (score 1):

Passphrase is defined by the way you created your private key. When creating a key pair you need to opt for no passphrase on the private key - this should solve your issue.